# Split text/string at closest space in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I'm really struggling how to split the text at the closest string to the 47th character.
How is this done?

```
var fulltext = document.getElementById("text").value;

var a = fulltext.slice(0, 47);
console.log(a);

var b = fulltext.slice(47, 47*2);
console.log(b);

var c = fulltext.slice(94, 47*3);
console.log(c);
```

Here is a JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f5n326gy/5/

Thanks.

Comment: Closest next of previous, or not important?

Comment: why not simplifying questions as much as possible, and posting `var fulltext = 'my text here directly and keep us focus directly on your problem'`

Comment: Hi, as long as the three lines of text read okay, I don't mind which. @dfsq

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are interested in just the first part, then use

```
var a = fulltext.match(/^.{47}\w*/)
```

**See demo (fiddle) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfquL8sp/).**

---

If you want to split the entire string to multiple substrings, then use

```
var a = fulltext.match(/.{47}\w*|.*/g);
```

**See demo (fiddle) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1aqyfe6k/).**

...and if you wish substrings do not start with the word separator (such as space or comma) and prefer to include it with the previous match, then use

```
var a = fulltext.match(/.{47}\w*\W*|.*/g);
```

**See demo (fiddle) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suyvd8h0/).**

Comment: This seems to work nicely for the first line. Would you be able to show me on jsfiddle how to split into three lines?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry @Ωmega - forgot to tag you

Comment: @TristanKirkpatrick - I have updated my answer. If that is not what you were looking for, please clarify your needs.

Comment: @Ωmega That splits the text perfectly in the console log. How can I then use each line as a variable. (it is to pass to a jQuery plugin)

e.g. 0 - 47 = a, 47 - 94 = b

Comment: @Ωmega One small problem, if three lines of text are not present I get an undefined error with a[1] and a [2], is there a way around this?

Comment: @TristanKirkpatrick - `[1,2].forEach(function(i){if(typeof a[i]==='undefined'){a[i]=''}})`

Comment: @Ωmega where would I put that code? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TristanKirkpatrick - Right after `var a = fulltext.match...` line, before you pass `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` to your another code.

Comment: @Ωmega it seems to work most of the time, but I've found a problem. With the text "Finish improving earlier sections by using the success criteria effectively." It doesn't seem to split it! Thanks

Comment: I prefer the indexOf solution but if you want the flexibility of the Regex try using `\S` instead of `\w` which will split it at the nearest [white-space like character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 8):

You can find the next word boundary using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method with `fromIndex` second parameter. After that you can use `slice` to get either left part or right one.

```js
var fulltext = "The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.";    
var before = fulltext.slice(0, fulltext.indexOf(' ', 47));
var after  = fulltext.slice(fulltext.indexOf(' ', 47));
alert(before);
alert(after);
```

Comment: This does seem to work although with some texts it will select a previous word and display it twice. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you give me an example of such text? can't imagine when it can happen.

Comment: I have been pasting in text from the internet and can't remember the exact text, sorry.