# How to start a new line with the previous line's word? String/Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, d3.js

I am using D3 to set some text, some of the strings are too long and
in the first line I want to cut it with '...' 
but on the second line how can I start the line with the whole word that was too long on the first line? or perhaps at the end of each last complete word that will fit, leave the '...' then start a new line?

my code:

```
 d3.selectAll('#titleTable').selectAll('td')
  .data(this.nodes)
  .enter()
  .filter(node => node.parent.id === clickedNode && node.extraExtraNode)
  .append('divname')
  .html(node => {
    const string = node.name.substring(35, 100);
    if (node.name && node.name.length > 35) {
      return ` <div class="nodepic"
       style="
       width: 27px;
       height: 27px;
       border-radius: 100%;
       position: relative;
       top: 17px;
       left: 10px;
       cursor: pointer;
       line-height: 10px;
       float: left;
       background: #eee no-repeat center;
       background-size: cover; background-image: url(https://ewsqa-images.weforum.org/products/${node.id}/standard)"> </div>
      <p class="nodeParagraph">${node.name.substring(0, 35)}..  ${string}</p>`;
    }
    return `<div class="nodepic"
     style=" width: 27px;
     height: 27px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     position: relative;
     top: 17px;
     left: 10px;
     line-height: 10px;
     float: left;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #eee no-repeat center;
     background-size: cover; background-image: url(https://ewsqa-images.weforum.org/products/${node.id}/standard)"> </div>
     <p class="nodeParagraph">${node.name} </p>`
  })
  .on('click', node => onClick(node))
```

}

at the moment I am trying to actually add in the rest of the string after the 'dots' by using string after the cut off point..of course this means that the words get cut off and then started again on the next line, at random!

Comment: why don't you put all the static style stuff in the style sheet, instead of duplicating it dozens of times in the code. the only variable stuff is the image URL. Is there a HTML tag `divname`? first you take a `substring` and then you test if the string exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split text/string at closest space in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758483/split-text-string-at-closest-space-in-javascript), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624713/js-splitting-a-long-string-into-strings-with-char-limit-while-avoiding-splittin

Answer (score -1):

2 possibilities

split your `node.name` on spaces,

```
var words = node.name.split(' ');
```

find the index in the word list that does exceed your `35` length after joining

```
words.slice(0,i).join(' ').length > 35
```

or use the following regular expression to split the string larger then 35 chars in two

```
/(.{1,35}\b)(.*)/
```

Comment: cannot find 'i'?

Comment: It didn't work, the first method, perhaps It's because of the 'i'

Comment: you need to add a for loop to find the index `i`, with the regex (you need to add a bit of code) you get the split without a for loop

Comment: Could you please show where I would add it in the code? and im not sure what to set the i < , to as its a string not an array

Comment: what in `for loop` and index `i` do you not get? do a search on `javascript for loop`

Comment: It doesnt work anyway! the ones that were previously too long now just say 'false'